# Better way to extract country wise player list from html file using regex

Tags: python, regex

## Problem statement:

**Make country wise player list from the following html code**

### HTML CODE:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Australia
        <ol>
            <li>Steven Smith</li>
            <li>David Warner</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        Bangladesh
        <ol>
            <li>Mashrafe Mortaza</li>
            <li>Tamim Iqbal</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        England
        <ol>
            <li>Eoin Morgan</li>
            <li>Jos Buttler</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Expected Output:

Australia- Steven Smith, David Warner

Bangladesh- Mashrafe Mortaza, Tamim Iqbal

England- Eoin Morgan, Jos Buttler

### My Code:

```
import re

with open('playerlist.html', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

mytext = re.sub(r'[\n\t]', '', text)

pat = r'<li>(\w+?)<ol><li>(\w+\s?\w+)</li><li>(\w+\s?\w+)</li>'

cpat = re.compile(pat)

result = cpat.findall(mytext)


for a,b,c in result:
    print('{0}- {1}, {2}'.format(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Regexps and HTML don’t go so well together. Better to parse the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions [is not the right tool when it comes to parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). There are specialized HTML parsers that would do a better job resulting into a more robust and less fragile solution.

Just to name a few problems that exists in your current approach:

- what if there are more than two players for a country
- what if there are 0 players for a country
- what if a country name contains a space or a single quote
- what if a player's name consists of more than two words or contains a single quote
- what if there are newlines after the opening or before the closing `li` tag

Instead, you may, for instance, use [`BeautifulSoup` library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('playerlist.html', 'r') as input_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_file, "html.parser")


for country in soup.select("ul > li"):
    country_name = country.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
    players = [player.get_text(strip=True) for player in country.select("ol > li")]

    print('{country} - {players}'.format(country=country_name,
                                         players=', '.join(players)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the hint of using a DOM parser given by others, you may also want to *separate your concerns* by splitting the parsing/grouping and processing/printing of the items.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString


def parse_players(html):
    """Parses players from the HTML text and groups them by country."""

    players_by_country = defaultdict(list)
    dom = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
    ul = dom.find('ul')

    for li in ul.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        for item in li.contents:
            if isinstance(item, NavigableString):
                country = item.strip()
                break

        ol = li.find('ol', recursive=False)

        for li_ in ol.find_all('li', recursive=False):
            players_by_country[country].append(''.join(li_.contents).strip())

    return players_by_country


def print_players(players_by_country):
    """Formats players of each country."""

    for country, players in players_by_country.items():
        print('{}- {}'.format(country, ', '.join(players)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_players(parse_players(HTML_TEXT))
```